# Compute $E[X^j Y^k]$ for $(X,Y) \sim N(0,\Sigma)$ using Isserlis' theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $(X,Y)$ be drawn from a 2-dimensional zero-mean multivariate normal distribution.
For $j,k$ non-negative integers, compute $E[X^j Y^k]$ using only $E[X^2]$, $E[Y^2]$, and $E[XY]$, using Isserlis' theorem.

I know that if $j+k$ is odd then the result is zero, but I am not sure about how to compute when $j+k$ is even for arbitrary $j$ and $k$. I realize that it is an inherently combinatorial problem, but I can't figure out how to enumerate all the possibilities as required by Isserlis' theorem. I have not worked with Isserlis' theorem in the past, but I'm pretty sure it's the key to computing this type of thing.

I see that a technique is outlined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Properties under "Higher moments", but I'm not sure how to generalize to arbitrary $j,k$.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z_i = X$ for $i = 1 \ldots j$ and $Z_i = Y$ for $i = j+1 \ldots j+k$. For convenience let's assume $j \le k$.
Isserlis says
$$ \mathbb E[X^j Y^k] = \mathbb E[Z_1 \ldots Z_{i+j}] = \sum_p \prod_{(s,t) \in p} \mathbb E[Z_s Z_t] $$
where the sum is over all perfect matchings $p$ of $[1,\ldots, j+k]$, i.e. all ways of partitioning $[1,\ldots, j+k]$ into unordered pairs.
Such a matching might have $r_1$ pairs where both elements are in $A = [1,\ldots,j]$; if so, it must have  $r_2 = j - 2 r_1$ pairs where one is in $A$ and the other in $B = [j+1,\ldots,j+k]$, and then
the remaining $r_3 = (j+k)/2 - (j - r_1) = r_1 + (k-j)/2$ pairs where
both are in $B$. Of course $r_1, r_2, r_3$ must be nonnegative. For such matchings we have a term of $\mathbb E[X^2]^{r_1} \mathbb E[XY]^{r_2} \mathbb E[Y^2]^{r_3}$.

Now you just have to count how many ways there are to choose such a matching.  There are ${j \choose 2 r_1}$ ways to choose which $2 r_1$ members of $A$ are matched together, and then $(2r_1 - 1)!! = (2r_1 - 1)(2r_1 - 3) \ldots 1$ ways of pairing them.  Similarly there are ${k \choose 2 r_3}$ ways to choose which $2 r_3$ members of $B$ are matched together, and $(2r_3 - 1)!!$ ways of pairing them.
That leaves $r_2 = j - 2 r_1$ members of $A$ and $k - 2 r_3$ members of $B$ which must be paired. Of course we need these to be equal, i.e. $r_3 = r_1 + (k-j)/2$, in which case there are  $r_2!$ ways to pair those members of $A$ with those members of $B$.  So we end up with
(for $j \le k$ with $j+k$ even)
$$ \mathbb E[X^j Y^k] = \sum_{r_1=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor}  {j \choose 2 r_1} (2 r_1 - 1)!! {k \choose 2 r_1 + k-j} (2 r_1 + k-j -1)!!\; (j - 2 r_1)! \;\mathbb E[X^2]^{r_1} \mathbb E[XY]^{j - 2 r_1} \mathbb E[Y^2]^{r_1 + (k-j)/2} $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $Z=(X,\ldots, X, Y, \ldots, Y)$ where $X$ is repeated $j$ times and $Y$ $k$ times. Can you prove that $Z$ is distributed as normal?

After how many pairs will give you $X^2$, $Y^2$ and $XY$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I already know that this is true, and my problem is I don't know how to actually enumerate all the different pairings with various numbers of XX, XY, and YY pairs and how many of each type there are. Could you please help me with this for arbitrary j,k?